# Use HttpClientUpgradeHandler to establish Websocketconnection?

Tags: websocket, netty, handshake

I try to establish a websocketconnection. But my websocketcontent keeps being rejected as not being readable. Right now I establish a connection by using the following handler stack:

```
p.addLast(ClientSslHandler),
p.addLast(new HttpClientCodec()),
p.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(8192)),
p.addLast(new WebSocketClientProtocolHandler(...)),
p.addlast(new myHandler);
```

The problem is (I think) that HttpClientCodec keeps encoding my Websocketframes as Httpframes. 
Thats why i think I can use HttpClientUpgradeHandler so deal with the handshake and then change to a pure Websocketconnection. Is this a viable solution? Or are there other workarounds?

Edit: changed WebSocketClientProtocolHandler to HttpClientUpgradeHandler

Edit2:
    public class ShipSocketClient {
        static final String URL = System.getProperty("url", "wss://10.2.3.44:4712");

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    URI uri = new URI(URL);
    String scheme = uri.getScheme() == null? "ws" : uri.getScheme();
    final String host = uri.getHost() == null? "127.0.0.1" : uri.getHost();
    final int port;
    if (uri.getPort() == -1) {
        if ("ws".equalsIgnoreCase(scheme)) {
            port = 80;
        } else if ("wss".equalsIgnoreCase(scheme)) {
            port = 443;
        } else {
            port = -1;
        }
    } else {
        port = uri.getPort();
    }

    if (!"ws".equalsIgnoreCase(scheme) && !"wss".equalsIgnoreCase(scheme)) {
        System.err.println("Only WS(S) is supported.");
        return;
    }

    final boolean ssl = "wss".equalsIgnoreCase(scheme);
    final SslContext sslCtx;
    if (ssl) {          
        List<String> CipherList = new ArrayList<String>();
        CipherList.add("TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256");
        //CipherList.add("TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8");
        CipherList.add("TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256");


    File vidksFile = new File("C:\\Users\\LETTAU\\Videos\\key.pem");
    File vidcertFile = new File("C:\\Users\\LETTAU\\Videos\\cert.pem");
    //CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");


    sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
            .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)                
            .ciphers(CipherList)
            .protocols("TLSv1.2")         
            .clientAuth(ClientAuth.REQUIRE)            
            .keyManager(vidcertFile, vidksFile)                            
            .build();  
    }
    else{
        sslCtx = null;
    }

    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try{

        WebSocketClientHandshaker wsHandShaker = WebSocketClientHandshakerFactory.newHandshaker(
                uri, WebSocketVersion.V13, "ship", false, new DefaultHttpHeaders());
        WebSocketClientProtocolHandler wsPrClHandler = new WebSocketClientProtocolHandler(wsHandShaker,true);            



        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(group)
         .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
         .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

             @Override
             protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {

                 ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                 SslHandler ClientSslHandler = sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc(), host, port);                     
                 HttpClientCodec sourceCodec = new HttpClientCodec(); 

                 //New approach with HttpClientUpgradeHandler
                 //ShipClientProtocolHandler is a class which extends WebSocketClientProtocolHandler implements HttpClientUpgradeHandler.UpgradeCodec
                 HttpClientUpgradeHandler httpToWsUpgrader = new HttpClientUpgradeHandler(sourceCodec, new ShipClientProtocolHandler(wsHandShaker,true), 8096);

                 if (sslCtx != null) {                       
                     p.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
                     p.addLast(ClientSslHandler);
                 }
                 p.addLast(                          
                         new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO),                          
                         sourceCodec,
                         new HttpObjectAggregator(8192),
                         //httpToWsUpgrader,
                         new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO),
                         wsPrClHandler);
                 }
             }
         );

        Channel ch = b.connect(uri.getHost(), port).sync().channel();


        BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while (true) {
            String msg = console.readLine();
            if (msg == null) {
                break;                
            } else if ("ping".equals(msg.toLowerCase())) {
                WebSocketFrame frame = new PingWebSocketFrame(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[] { 8, 1, 8, 1 }));
                ch.writeAndFlush(frame);
            } else if ("cmi".equals(msg.toLowerCase())) {    
                ByteBuf bBuf = Unpooled.buffer(16);
                bBuf.writeByte(0);
                bBuf.writeByte(0);
                BinaryWebSocketFrame bytebuffer = new BinaryWebSocketFrame(bBuf); 
                ch.writeAndFlush(bytebuffer);
            } else if ("cdp".equals(msg.toLowerCase())) { 
                ByteBuf bBuf = Unpooled.buffer(1000);
                //bBuf.writeByte(0);
                //bBuf.writeByte(1);
                ByteBufUtil.writeUtf8(bBuf,"{\"connectionHello\":[{\"phase\":\"ready\"},{\"waiting\":60000}]}");
                BinaryWebSocketFrame bytebuffer = new BinaryWebSocketFrame(bBuf);                   
                ch.writeAndFlush(bytebuffer);                   
            } else {
                WebSocketFrame frame = new TextWebSocketFrame(msg);                    
                ch.writeAndFlush(frame);                    
            }
        }
    } finally {
        group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
```

Edit3: Some addtitional Information on why i think HttpClientCodec is the problem:
This is what a received package looks like:

```
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 88 1d 11 30 53 54 41 54 45 5f 57 41 49 54 5f 43 |...0STATE_WAIT_C|
|00000010| 4c 4f 53 45 5f 43 4f 4e 4e 45 43 54 49 4f 4e    |LOSE_CONNECTION |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

This is what an outgoing package looks like:

```
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 82 9d 12 1e 8c 5a 12 1f f7 78 71 71 e2 34 77 7d |.....Z...xqq.4w}|
|00000010| f8 33 7d 70 c4 3f 7e 72 e3 78 28 3c fe 3f 73 7a |.3}p.?~r.x(<.?sz|
|00000020| f5 78 6f                                        |.xo             |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upgrade to WebSockets you should use the `WebSocketClientHandshaker`.

Netty itself contains an example for it:

https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/netty-4.1.28.Final/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/client

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I did not make the problem clear enough. But with my code i am able to upgrade to Websockets. Unfortunally the HttpClientCodec keeps encoding my Websocketframes(i think). That's why i want to use HttpClientUpgradeHandler. But im not sure if this is an appropriate solution as i could not find anyone else who did it that way. I would need to implement HttpClientUpgradeHandler.UpgradeCodec for WebsocketClientProtocolHandler.